# Expose controller property to route's model function

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I've defined some properties in a controller for a pagination:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  limit: 1,
  skip: 0,
  pageSize: 1
  }
});
```

I'd like to access `limit` in the Route's `model`-function but I don't know how.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

   model: function(params) {

      console.log(this.get('controller').get('limit')) <- doesnt work for example
      return this.store.find('post', {limit: 1,
                                      sort:'createdAt desc'});
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should take a look at the queryParams option (http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/).

With query params you can set the limit to be a query param in your URL like `http://yourdomain.com/someroute?limit=15`.

Your controller will become:

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    queryParams: ['limit'],  // Here you define your query params
    limit: 1                 // The default value to use for the query param
});
```

You route will become:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('post', {
            limit: params.limit, // 'limit' param is available in params
            sort:'createdAt desc'
        });
    }
});
```

**Alternative:**

If you don't want to use query params, another solution might be to define the limit property in one of the parent route's controller. By doing so you can access the property in the model hook by doing:

```
this.controllerFor('parentRoute').get('limit');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't want to use any Query Parameters to accomplish this.

Comment: Alright, than from what I know there is no way to get a controller property from the model hook, because the controller is not set up yet there. You can define the limit property in a parent route's controller and access it via `this.controllerFor('parentroute').get('limit')` though.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I needed. Could you add it to your anser as an alternative so I can mark it answered?